# Is there a way to group and map multiple subcollection streams?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a user collection in the firestore which has 2 subcollections, private and public. I want to get a user model in a Stream. So I get the snapshot of the user document and map it to a user model. But how does this work when I have those two subcollections? Because both subcollections will need their own stream right? How can I combine this into one user model? This is what I have thus far, my problem started when I was trying to get the private and public subcollections in my user model from my snapshot and realized they are both their own stream. Also I would like to keep any async stuff out of my user model. I now think I need to somehow make a stream that maps both sub collection documents to a single model, but how do I do this?

**UserModel**

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

    class UserModel {

      final String id;
      final String phoneNumber;
      final String name;

      UserModel._internal({
        @required this.id,
        @required this.phoneNumber,
        @required this.name,
      })  : assert(id != null),
      assert(phoneNumber != null),
      assert(name != null);

      factory UserModel.fromFirebase(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      {
        return UserModel._internal(
          id: snapshot.documentID ?? '',
//snapshot is a stream so this will be async which is not nice. Should I map both public and private into one usermodel somehow?
          phoneNumber: snapshot.reference.collection('public').document('data'). ?? '',
//snapshot is a stream so this will be async which is not nice. Should I map both public and private into one usermodel somehow?
          name: snapshot.reference.collection('public').document('data').  ?? '',
        );
      }

    }
```

**UserProvider**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:app_name/data/models/user_authentication_certificate.dart';
import 'package:app_name/data/models/user_model.dart';

class UserProvider {
  static const userCollectionKey = 'users';
  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection(userCollectionKey);

  Stream<UserModel> me(UserAuthenticationCertificate certificate) {
    return userCollection.document(certificate.userID).snapshots().map((snapshot) =>
        UserModel.fromFirebase(snapshot));
  }
}
```

**Edit**

I thought I solved this by zipping the streams. But as it turns out that it only seems to emit when every stream has changed. Any solution for that?

```
  Stream<UserModel> me(UserAuthenticationCertificate certificate) {
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> userData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).snapshots();
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> privateUserData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).collection('private').document('data').snapshots();
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> publicUserData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).collection('public').document('data').snapshots();
    return StreamZip([userData, privateUserData, publicUserData]).asBroadcastStream().map((snapshot) => UserModel.fromFirebase(snapshot));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using rxdart to use CombineLatestStream which does exactly what I needed!

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'dart:async';

  Stream<UserModel> me(UserAuthenticationCertificate certificate) {
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> userData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).snapshots();
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> privateUserData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).collection('private').document('data').snapshots();
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> publicUserData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).collection('public').document('data').snapshots();
    return CombineLatestStream([userData, privateUserData, publicUserData], (values) => values.toList()).asBroadcastStream().map((snapshot) => UserModel.fromFirebase(snapshot));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Merge both Streams using MergeStream from RxDart 
here is the Link to the Docs

https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/MergeStream-class.html

and here another Link to understand how it is work

https://rxmarbles.com/#merge

Comment: You can also do that with StreamGroup.merge(). And the problem with that approach is that it give a problem with my map since it emits for every stream my model will only be mapped to the last stream. Which is not what I want. I want it to have the combined values of every stream.

Comment: nice the CombineLatestStream give you one object is a list of all the information that you need.
i tryed and it work

Comment: give me up then haha thank you i looked for all rxdart streams

Comment: it is wine wine

Comment: @MikeOttink I have used `StreamGroup.merge` like `Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamFinal = StreamGroup.merge([streamOne, streamTwo]);`, any suggestion will be welcome :) Thanks.